# Log Shipped but Won't Update

Tags: sql-server-2005, log-shipping

I'm currently taking the MS SQL 2K5 Admin course at a local college and ran into a problem with the Log Shipping part.

My setup is the following:

Windows 7 x64
SQL 2005 SP3
2 SQL server instances on the same machine

Log Shipping settings:

1. Performed full then log back up of Primary
2. Manually restore on Secondary in STANDBY MODE
3. Insert a new record into the table
4. Set up Log Shipping on Primary using SQL Authenication login to connect to the Secondary
5. Set up timers and copy destination on Secondary
6. Monitoring instance not being used

I set up a shared folder for WORKGROUP so both instances on the machine can read & write to it.  I can see transaction logs generated and copied as defined by the Transaction Shipping wizard.  However, the specified table on the Secondary instance is not updating.

Comment: Please show your job log, or are you no longer interested in a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If my transaction logging doesn't work I check the following:

1. Check if the t-logs are available on
   the secondary server.
2. Are there any output report files for the job steps present.
3. Try running the restore job manually and check the report files
   than if any errors occured
4. Try restoring the next transaction manually

Keep in mind that there can be a lot of problems with transaction logging directly or indirectly caused by log shipping.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [SQLAgent jobs](http://wiki.tekkies.co.uk/SQLServer_log_shipping#Components) on the destination server: Look at the LSCopy and LSRestore jobs.  If they are failing, look at the job log.  Post the error message in the question for more help.

See common pitfalls [here](http://wiki.tekkies.co.uk/SQLServer_log_shipping#Secondary_server_cannot_connect_to_the_primary)